# When I use yolov3 to train my dataset and there are more than 60 objects in a picture,do I need to change yolov3.cfg or other parameters?

Tags: python, tensorflow, computer-vision, yolo, darknet

When I use yolov3 to train my dataset and there are more than 60 objects in a picture,and these objects are very dense, the final train-loss is 16.4,do I need to change yolov3.cfg or other parameters?or what can I do to reduce the train-loss?

Answer (score 0):

From your question I understand that there are many small objects in your images. You could do a few things to improve your training-loss:

- set flag `random=1` in your `.cfg-file` - it will increase precision by training Yolo for different resolutions.
- increase network resolution in your `.cfg-file` (`height=608, width=608` or any value multiple of 32) - it will increase precision.

Also I'd suggest you to have some test images and check your `mAP` while training to if the model's detection accuracy is increasing as the loss goes down.

Comment: thanks for your answer, I checked my dataset,and found that there are many objects in a picture,but they aren't small,when the picture is resized to 416*416, the scale of objects is larger than 16*16. Then, I calculated mAP, it's 93.7%. then I use kmeans to generate my own anchors.I trained the network with my own anchors and calculated mAP again. the loss goes down to 15.8 and the mAP is 98.88%.

Comment: I think the reason why the mAP is so high is that my test set is very similar to the training set, because I first enhanced 650 images to 4800, and then selected the test set, I did this because if the test set was selected at first, the number will be too small. Do you have any good comments，please

Comment: For the test set, I'd suggest to collect another set of data which has similar noise to what you'd expect in real world inference. Also I'm wondering if you're using the pre-trained weights for Yolov3. And as I see your `mAP` is quite high, why are you worried about training loss? Is the accuracy low during actual inference?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion,I am planning to use another dataset for testing.I used the original yolov3.weights that is for coco dataset，but I use it to train completely different objects.In fact,I observed that the boxes detected by trained model are also accurate. I just saw that some papers using yolov3 have very small loss values: a few tenths, so I am a bit confused.I think the loss is mainly caused by the accuracy of the prediction box.